# Change navbar button text from menu drawer

Tags: angularjs, steroids, supersonic

I am building an app for a scheduler using Appgyver Steroids, and on the navbar, I have a button to switch days, but I can't figure out how to switch de label:

**index.html**

```
<script src="/scripts/application.js"></script>
<super-navbar-button ng-bind="dayTitle" side="right" onclick="supersonic.ui.drawers.open('right')">Day</super-navbar-button>
```

**drawerMenu.html**

```
<script src="/scripts/application.js"></script>
<li class="item" onclick="supersonic.ui.drawers.close('right')" ng-model="day" ng-click="newDay()">Monday</li>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<li class="item" onclick="supersonic.ui.drawers.close('right')" ng-model="day" ng-click="newDay()">Tuesday</li>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

**application.js**

```
angular.module('SteroidsApplication', [
  'supersonic'
  ])
.controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic) {

  $scope.newDay= function(){
    supersonic.logger.log("Got here");
    $scope.dayTitle= $scope.day;
  }
});
```

Right now I'm not even logging the "Got here" text, probably I have a minor error or something I'm missing. This is my first steroids/supersonic/angular/hybrid application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put `supersonic.ui.drawers.open('right')` inside `$scope.newDay` function. Remove `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

two things dont do onclick with angular, instead do ng-click

did you tried doing

```
{{ day }}
```

instead of writing the day?